# Calculate average for 5 star review system based on average and quantity of reviews

Tags: bayesian, average

I have a review system and I stumble over the fact that I want to make a fair ranking and not just the average. The average is allready calculated but when you are sorting on this average the results are not fair.

EXAMPLE:

Company A has an average score of 4.8 based on 5 reviews. Company B has an average score of 4.7 based on 43 reviews.

If you rank on average score Company A is above Company B in ranking but I think it ain't fair because it is a lot harder to get a 4.7 based on 43 reviews.

I want to create a number that is based on the average review score and the number of reviews that are submitted.

Maybe I am wrong here for asking this question but what is the best formula to create such an average and wich values do I need for creating this?

I am developing in PHP if this should be important for you to know.

If anyone could help me out that would be great.

**EDIT**
Ok, so this shoud do the trick? If I add this data to the formula the ranking should be better and most important more fair?

```
$avg_num_votes = 3.852941176470588; // Average number of reviews that are written for all company's on the website
$avg_rating = 4.822222222; // Average rating for all company's that are on the website that have a review
$this_num_votes = 1; // Number of reviews that are written for this company
$this_rating = 5; // Average rating of this company

$bayesian_rating = ( ($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + ($this_num_votes * $this_rating) ) / ($avg_num_votes + $this_num_votes);

echo $bayesian_rating;
```

Comment: Little birds whispered to my ear something about Bayesian averages ... https://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-average-ratings.html

Comment: @MattiP. Thank you for the response. I edited my answer, so this should do the trick?

Comment: (1) This is a statistics question. You might get more answers on the statistics stackexchange forum. (2) You might be interested in empirical Bayes estimation, as described in this article: http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/